# Confirmation Dialog on Browser back / close button

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces 4.0

If there are unsaved changes on the page, I would like to show Primefaces' confirmation dialog on browser back / close button click. I am not sure how to achieve this.

window.onbeforeunload always shows the browser's alert box. I need to override it with Primefaces' confirmation dialog.

Comment: Have your tried the following? `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return PF('widget').show(); };`

Comment: Yes, I tried but it does not work.